# How to specify cardinality in Core Data for iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, xcode5

I have an entity in my data core model and I would like to tell to Xcode that this entity has maximum one record. Is it possible to do that? If yes, can you tell me how?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

If that record is a relationship, specify it as a "to one" relationship on the right hand pane of the model editor (last tab there)